# what library that can be used to convert bitmap to vector?

Tags: c++, image-processing, graphics, vector-graphics, bitmapimage

My current project is related to bitmap to vector. so far i found these libraries:

[potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)

- (+) really good for line tracing
- (+) documentation
- (-) does not support image gradient

[ardeco](http://alice.loria.fr/WIKI/index.php/Graphite/Ardeco)

- (+) support olor gradient
- (+) documentation
- (-) line tracing is inferior compared to potrace
- (-) outdated (2006)

[rastertovector](https://code.google.com/p/rastertovector/)

- (+) support color gradient
- (-) little documentation
- (-) line tracing is inferior compared to potrace
- (-) little bit outdated (2008)

the project will be used to vectorize cartoon image (comic or cartoon, specifically). My main goal is just vectorizing black and white image. So potrace gives me sufficient result, but i would like to process gradient, for example, gradually from black to white.

so far, it's quite hard to find library that support color gradient. Ardeco and rastertovector support color gradient, but they are a little bit outdated. I am wondering if there is any well-maintained (and of course, well documented) vector-tracing library out there

Thanks!

Comment: Just note that some people may recommend Autotrace, which is not maintained and has never gotten past beta. (The latest version, 0.31.1, was released in 2002).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)? Perhaps these other threads can be useful for you:

- [Convert raster images to vector graphics using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894507/convert-raster-images-to-vector-graphics-using-opencv)
- [PHP image trace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266556/php-image-trace-function)

And also these tutorials:

- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

Comment: As per the article, "Convert raster images to vector graphics using OpenCV?", the most popular answer states that there is no vectorization tool readily available.